# datepicker with range validation as well as with default date showing in textbox as today

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker, uidatepicker

```
$(function() {
var d = new Date();

    $("#Start_validBeforeDatepicker").datepicker(
        {
        defaultDate: d,
        numberOfMonths : 1,
        showButtonPanel : true,
        onClose : function(selectedDate) {

            $("#End_validAfterDatepicker").datepicker("option","minDate", selectedDate);

        }
    });
    $("#End_validAfterDatepicker").datepicker(
    {
        defaultDate: +1, 
        setDate:new Date(),
        numberOfMonths : 1,
        showButtonPanel : true,
        onClose : function(selectedDate) {                  
            $("#Start_validBeforeDatepicker").datepicker("option","maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });
});
```

this is my datepciker script..

I want to initialize my both of datepicker with the todays date..and also i want that `Start_validBeforeDatepicker` always `<= #End_validAfterDatepicker` so how can i do that..can anyone please guide me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is the code for validating date range.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flick/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function()
{
    $( "#issuedate" ).datepicker(
    {
        minDate: new Date(),
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate )
        {
            $( "#expdate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });

    $( "#expdate" ).datepicker(
    {
        minDate: new Date(),
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate )
        {
            $( "#issuedate" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="issuedate" />
<input type="text" id="expdate" />
```

All you need to do is set parameter accordingly.